# How to get sum of same value and different value in same row?

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, pivot

**table 1** 
invno  percentage    cost 
  1           18%        18.00  
  1           18%        18.00  
  2           18%        18.00  
  2           28%        28.00  

**table 2**
 id  percentage
  1    18%
  2    28%

The table 2 `percentage` column values should become the column headings of output.

In table 1, `invno` 1 has 2 entries, but the same percentage value of `18%`; `invno` 2 has 2 entries with different percentage values.

**output**

```
invno    percentage 18%    percentage 28%
  1           36.00             0.00
  2           18.00            28.00
```

So far I have written:

```
SELECT
    `invno`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `percentage` = '18' THEN `percentage` ELSE NULL END) AS `percentage_18`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `percentage` = '28' THEN `percentage` ELSE NULL END) AS `percentage_28`
FROM `table1`
GROUP BY `invno`
HAVING 18 IS NOT NULL AND 28 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY `invno`
```

This is fine, but I want to get the percentages dynamically.

Comment: *please give me mysql query for this output* how about trying something yourself first.

Comment: how many percentage  you have  ???  just two or more ?

Comment: i don't know how to ask question in here . this my first time .so please help me

Comment: If I understand your task, you will need to write some kind of a JOIN (depending on your needs), then use a pivot technique to generate the sums.  Here's a lead...https://stackoverflow.com/a/51321042/2943403

Comment: The question is fine as far as it goes, but as pointed out - you are expected to make some attempt at solving the problem.  Have you written any code so far?

Comment: i don't know how to set  table2 result as a output column name .

Comment: @Rohith you may need to query table 2 first, then construct a dynamic query on table 1 using the results from table 1.

Comment: @mickmackusa  for me the question was not even closed expecially for a new contributor

Comment: @Rohith I whacked together a quick working solurion on my localhost.  I'll post a solution once the page is reopened.  Just a refinement in advance, I recommend that you remove the trailing `%` from your table values and set the column type as int or decimal depending on your expected percentage values.

Comment: How to get reopen vote?

Comment: A closed question that has been edited goes into a "queue" to be reviewed.  If 5 volunteers decide that the question has been edited to become answerable, then their 5 votes re-open the question.  (beyond the Review Queue, if any passer-by decide that it should not be closed, they can vote to re-open as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over a bowl of cereal this morning, I quickly scratched out a two-step approach to generate your desired output in a dynamic fashion.

```
if (!$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root","","dbname")) {
    echo "Database Connection Error"; // $conn->connect_error
} else {
    if (!$result = $conn->query("SELECT DISTINCT percentage FROM percents ORDER BY percentage")) {
        echo "Syntax Error"; // $conn->error
    } else {
        $select_columns = ['invno'];
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $percent = (int)$row['percentage'];
            $select_columns[] = "SUM(CASE WHEN percentage = {$percent} THEN `percentage` ELSE 0 END) AS percentage_{$percent}";
        }
        if (!$result = $conn->query("SELECT " . implode(', ', $select_columns) . " FROM invoices GROUP BY invno ORDER BY invno")) {
            echo "Syntax Error"; // $conn->error
        } else {
            echo "<table border=1>";
                foreach ($result as $index => $row) {
                    if (!$index) {
                        echo '<tr><th>' , implode('</th><th>', array_keys($row)) , '</th></tr>';
                    }
                    echo '<tr><td>' , implode('</td><td>', $row) , '</td></tr>';
                }
            echo "</table>";
        }
    }
}
```

Effectively, I queried for unique percentage values from table2, then used those values to dynamically construct the `SUM(CASE...))` expressions on table1.  If this doesn't exactly work as you require on your actual project data, please supply a better/larger representation of your db data which isolates the issue so that I can update my answer.